# Why is a smiley face zooming my page?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, zooming

So, I visited this website called [copypastecharacter.com](http://copypastecharacter.com). I was wanting to get HTML codes for icons. I saw the following feature on the site:

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

I thought this feature was to track how popular the current page was. The closer the circle was to the smiley face, the more popular these particular HTML codes were. I clicked on the smiley face to like the page, but instead *zoomed* the page.

**Isn't this terrible UX? Who associates a smiley or frowning face as an application for zooming? Is there any research supporting why this feature exists?**

Comment: Yes, it's bad UX. The question is otherwise not really appropriate for the SE format. You're simply asking for our opinion and if we've seen it before. There is not usability concept or concern here.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey Great point! I've added more details to my question. I'm not asking for opinions, I'm asking for research on why the web developer should or should not make this feature. You and I both agree this was a bad UX world, but does research? They may need users to zoom in and a smiley face triggers this need to zoom in? It did for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hope that this is not intentional.

Having inspected the page I can see that these are not placed as graphics. They are placed as text characters which would suggest the original developer had something else in mind such as a custom font or a different characterset (utf-8 instead of ISO-8859-8 for example).

If not, then this is just plain bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the design is intentional, even though the idea behind this is terrible for a zoom slider, it seems the developer had something different in his mind when he designed this.

There is a slight difference in the font size of the symbols that are being used.

[image]

In the defense of the developer, he might have assumed this might convey the idea that the slider, when moved from one symbol to the other, would resize all the symbols in the page accordingly.

This would be a great example for how not to describe an interactive element. The least expensive tweak he could do to make this (somewhat) viable is to use the same symbol at different sizes on the two sides of the slider.